# Regex: Grouping with OR

Tags: logic, grouping, operator-keyword, regexp-replace

I'm new here, so please don't scold me for misspellings etc.

What I need to do is to rename a bunch of files with a date in different formats at the beginning of their names, like:

```
05.07.2020-abc.pdf

2020.07.05-pqr.pdf
```

Instead of writing a different expression for each formatting, eg.

```
^(\d{2})\.(\d{2}).(\d{4})(.+) => $3-$2-$1$4
```

Example

```
02.11.2022-abc.pdf => 2022-11-02-abc.pdf
```

I'd like to do it in one fell swoop using the OR operator "|" but I have no idea how to formulate the groupings etc. Can one have nested groupings in regex?

Any ideas? Thank in advance!

@The fourth bird:

No `(.+)` needed. You're right, I condensed my actual expression and could have taken it out.

The different date 'formats' I mean are `dd.mm.yyyy` and `yyyy.mm.dd` respectively, and I need to convert both to `yyyy-mn-dd`

So,if the format is dd.mm.yyyy I have to flip the string, so to say, else I just need  to replace the dots by hyphens.

The OS is Android, and for this operation I use Solid Explorer multi search & replace using regex.

I hope I made myself clear this time around ;-)

Comment: You don't need `(.+)` and `$4` What are the different types of formats and what is the tool or language?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Having problems here, I'll expand in my original text.